# How should Symantec Endpoint Protection be set up on an IIS 6 web and SQL 2008 server

Tags: sql-server, iis-6, symantec

We have a small server running a couple of internal classic asp and .net websites.  SQL 2008 is also installed on this box.

How should Endpoint Protection be configured to not screw with the normal functioning of the apps?

Comment: is "not at all" an option? ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately no.  The sys admin insists on it being installed.  I had a helluva time just getting MS's platform installer to work.. until I temporarily disabled the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's strange. It sounds like the sysadmin has a sense of ownership of the server if he's insisting that it be installed. It also sounds like he is the AV administrator, but it doesn't sound like he knows what AV exclusions to configure on a web and SQL server. 
Is that the case?

Have a look here: http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/scassells/archive/2007/05/14/what-anti-virus-scanning-exclusions-should-be-considered-for-system-and-servers.aspx.

And here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943556.

Comment: Yes that is the case.  He's the network admin in a mid size company.  Their IT resources are, shall we say, lacking in the knowledge department.  I had a heck of a time just getting SQL 2008 to install.  Symantec kept modifying the msi file.  When I turned it off, it would turn itself back on 45 seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the Management console, Create Exclusions / Centralized Exceptions for files with the following extentions -

*.MDF ; *.NDF and *.LDF

Additionally, create an exception for the folder where your database data files (*.MDF ; *.NDF and *.LDF) are going to be stored

Not sure waht the imapct on IIS will be.  Not aware of any specific exceptions needed.

Is any part of the SEPP arcitecture on the box other than the client?